# Loop to create random numbers, read from existing array, then create new array -- Stuck in While-Loop

Tags: c, for-loop, random, while-loop

I have a doozy of a conundrum. Conceptually, I think I know what I need to do. Code-wise, I'm not so sure.

I want to go through the `AVAIL_NURSE_W1[]` array (which holds the number that corresponds to which nurse is available on Week_1), generate a random number to decide on a slot in that array (if the slot holds a zero value, then generate another random number and try again), take that number (which is a nurse), and put it into the `MONDAY[]` array.

Related-code:

```
int main() {

int randomNurse();
srand(time_t(NULL));

/*0 = Denise, 1 = Inja, 2 = Jane, 3 = Karen, 4 = Maggie, 5 = Margaret, 6 = MJ, 7 = Queen, 8 = Sherri*/


/*-----WEEKLY_ASSIGNMENT-----*/

int AVAIL_NURSE_W1[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }; //holds the numerical values of the nurses that CAN work each week

/*scans in first week*/
for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++) {
    for (int num = 0; num < 9; num++) {
        if (AVAIL_NURSE_W1[num] == select[0][column])
            AVAIL_NURSE_W1[num] = 0;
    }
}


/*-----MONDAY-----*/
int MONDAY[5]; //days of the week, number of jobs on a given day
for (int e = 0; e < 5; e++) { //loop for positions on monday
    while (MONDAY[e] == 0) {
        int temp_assign = randomNurse();
        if (AVAIL_NURSE_W1[temp_assign] != 0) { //if the nurse IS available...
            MONDAY[e] = AVAIL_NURSE_W1[temp_assign];
            AVAIL_NURSE_W1[temp_assign] = 0; //we don't want to repeat nurses
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
} 

return 0;
}

/*function to generate random nurse*/
int randomNurse() {

return rand() % 9; //random number 0-8, to pick nurse
}
```

**My Question:**
How do I take care of getting the available nurses from the `AVAIL_NURSE_W1[]` array, generate a random number which decides which slot to take a value from, takes that value, stores it in a new array `MONDAY[]`; if the value in the `AVAIL_NURSE_W1[]` array is a ZERO, then repeat the above process until it's selected a non-zero value; after I've selected a value, I will change the selected value to a ZERO and then go through the loop again.

***Desired result***
The `MONDAY[]` array should contain five non-zero integers. No repeats.

So far, it seems the `while` loop condition never changes.

Let me know if there is anything else that needs saying. I hope I've given enough information.

Comment: What is happening in the segment commented `scans in first week`? Where is `select` declared and where is it filled with data?

Comment: @dreamlax I left that code out because last time I posted a question regarding this, it was put "on-hold, because it was off-topic for having too much information."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char names[9][10] = {"Denise", "Inja", "Jane", "Karen", "Maggie", "Margaret",       "MJ", "Queen", "Sherri"};
const char days[5][10] = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
int randomNurse();

int main() {


srand(time(NULL));
int day, e, pos, candidate;
int i,j;

/*0 = Denise, 1 = Inja, 2 = Jane, 3 = Karen, 4 = Maggie, 5 = Margaret, 6 = MJ, 7 = Queen, 8 = Sherri*/


/*-----WEEKLY_ASSIGNMENT-----*/

int AVAIL_NURSE_W1[9] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}; //holds the status of each nurse, 1:available 0:unavailable

int pos_per_day[5] = {2, 5, 7, 4, 3}; // number of needed nurses per day, Monday:2 nurses, tuesday: 5 nurses ...

int select[5][9]; // the selected nurses per day 
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
for(j=0; j<9;j++) select[i][j] = -1; // initialize to -1 which means no nurse is selected


// fill all the days of week 

for (day = 0; day<5; day++)   // for every day
{
    for(pos = 0; pos<pos_per_day[day]; pos++ ) // for every position needed that day
    {
        do
        {
            candidate = randomNurse();
        }while(!AVAIL_NURSE_W1[candidate]); // look for available nurse

        AVAIL_NURSE_W1[candidate] = 0;  // change her status to not available
        select[day][pos] = candidate;   // fill the output array with appropriate nurse
    }
    for(i=0; i< 9; i++)
    {
        AVAIL_NURSE_W1[i] = 1; // initialize the nurses status for next day use
    }
}

for(i=0; i<5; i++) // display 
{
    printf("%-10s: ", days[i]);
    for(j=0; j<9;j++) 
    {
        if(select[i][j] != -1) printf("%-10s ", names[select[i][j]]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


return 0;
}

/*function to generate random nurse*/
int randomNurse() {

return rand() % 9; //random number 0-8, to pick nurse
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to have it so a user can input values of nurses to disregard for scheduling purposes. Could you please look at the code here: [Pastebin - Nurse Schedule](http://pastebin.com/1yDaNFh4) and let me know what further changes would be necessary? I can't figure it out.

Comment: At glance, I would say this line `avail_nurses[i] = 1; //initialize the nurses status for next day use` will initialize to 0 slackers, think about it a bit. I also would like to suggest you one more efficient way to use flags, it should be better/easy to handle than the arrays